# Simpler derivation of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that the equality $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$ can be proved in numerous ways by using the Fourier series. However, is there a way to derive it using more fundamental tools? I've tried:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 x^{n-1} dx \int_0^1 y^{n-1} dy = \int_0^1 dx\int_0^1 dy \frac{1}{1-xy}$$ 
and by changing variables I was able to write it in several other forms:$$ = -\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x} dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln (1+t)}{t(1+t)} dt = \int_0^\infty \frac{u }{e^u -1}du $$
but that's as far as I could get.

I specifically don't want to use Fourier series. More fundamental complex analysis, like contour integration, is fine.

Comment: This problem is called the Basel Problem and here is a list of proofs for it : https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Basel_Problem  It might help you

Comment: A very elementary proof is here (just elementary algebra, and the squeeze theorem for limits): https://math.stackexchange.com/a/8353/1242

Comment: For what it's worth, you may find [this video](https://youtu.be/d-o3eB9sfls) interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. Actually, that's what Tom Apostol did in an article he published in 1983; you can read the proof [here](https://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/etc/zeta2.pdf) (it's the first proof). He used a change of variable ($(x,y)\mapsto(x+y,x-y)$) in order to compute the integral$$\iint_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}\frac1{1-xy}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy.$$

Comment: It's older than that; see the comment here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/621906/1242

Comment: @HansLundmark That's interesting. Thanks.